# Image view is not created after referenced the library project to another project

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, imageview

I have created a Android Library application with some activity containing a imageviews. It works fine, but when I mark it as a library and reference in another application, it is giving errors Null pointer Exception when I am trying to get the Image View using findViewById(R.id.imgdisplay).

when I referenced the library project to my-project `(Project_Name --> properties --> Java built path )` add jar file. And I compiled the project at that time the library project and `R.java` is included in gen folder  but the `R.java` getting the IDs Resource are same in my project. Here its not generated  the actual library project of R.java. Why?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that the R.java of the library project isn't included in your gen folder of your application?

Comment: Hi Amokrane chentir, is it possible please rply.. Thank you